# Convert octal number to string value by using sqlite statements in ios

Tags: ios

im trying to add a octal value into sqlite query of my project, but i couldn't able to get the corresponding response from database, this is the query that im using in my project INSERT INTO players VALUES(35,NULL,NULL,'1970-01-01 00:00:00','1970-01-01 00:00:00',35,'Mani Kandan\047');
   Here the last value is the name field which is contains the octal value of \047(as string ').

Answer (score 0):

This may not be exactly what you need, but it should start you off.

```
NSRegularExpression *exp = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\\\([0-7]{3})"
                                                                     options:0
                                                                       error:NULL];
NSString *string = @"VALUES(35,\\066,NULL,NULL,'1970-01-01 00:00:00','1970-01-01 00:00:00',35,'Mani Kandan\\047');";
NSMutableString *stringM = [string mutableCopy];
// Go reverse so that the ranges in later matches don't get moved.
for (NSTextCheckingResult *result in [[exp matchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])] reverseObjectEnumerator])
{
    NSRange range = [result rangeAtIndex:1];
    NSString *octal = [string substringWithRange:range];
    NSLog(@"Oct: %@", octal);
    long decimal = strtol([octal UTF8String], NULL, 8);
    NSLog(@"Dec: %ld", decimal);
    NSString *hex = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lx", decimal];
    NSLog(@"Hex: %@", hex);

    [stringM replaceCharactersInRange:range withString:hex];
}
NSLog(@"\nOrigin: %@\nResult: %@", string, stringM);
```